# A sorted list with segment control, yet stable state

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list of objects to be displayed using List. I also have SegmentControl to control the way of sorting. Here is my code:

```
func getSortedObjs() -> [MyObject] {
    
    var sortedObjs: [MyObject] = []
    
    if selectedSortState == SightingSortState.name {
        sortedObjs = objs.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    } else {
        sortedObjs = objs.sorted { $0.date! < $1.date! }
    }
    
    return sortedObjs
}
```

The segment control will help to determine whether selectedSortState is equal to name or others.
My List implementation as follows:

```
List {
                ForEach(getSortedObjs(), id: \.self) { obj in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ObjDetailView(obj: obj)) {
                        VStack {
                            Text(obj.name).font(.body)
                            Text(obj.date).font(.body)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                Button(action: {self.showingExporter.toggle()}) {
                    Label("Export", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

It works fine. However, there is warning always appear says:
"[SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."
whenever I click on the segment control, which cause my list shuffle.
How can I avoid the problem? I am afraid it will cause crash

Comment: Is the content of the array static or is it changing over time? For static content you should sort only once, before the ForEach. For dynamic content it might be better to sort the array close to where you are changing it

Comment: It looks like you are storing the list in your view. Don't do that. Use a view model.

Comment: How can I do that before the ForEach? Cause the user click on the Segment, I should sort and display the sorted list immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that it is the .animation() caused the UI not refresh as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug of not-refreshed `NavigationView` in `View2`.

The possible workaround (tasted with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4) is to force-refresh it (disclaimer: as any workaround it might have bad side effects or might stop working at any time).

Anyway for your consideration the demo of idea:

```
struct View2: View {
    @State private var deferredID: Int?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                Text("this is view 2")
                    .onAppear{
                        print("view 2 on appear")
                        if nil == deferredID {
                            deferredID = 1
                        }
                    }
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .id(deferredID ?? 0)
    }
}
```